# How to access and change CDialog members from a different class

Tags: c++, visual-studio, dialog

I've got a Dialog-based Application.
By default Visual Studio created an App and a Dlg class.
In the App's InitInstance, to show the dialog box, there is a declaration CMyDlg dlg, then a dlg.DoModal().

My question is, how do I access dlg members from my other classes?  For instance, I created an edit box with a control variable associated with it.  I want one of my other classes to set the text of the edit box and display it.

Help much appreciated.

Comment: The most common method in MFC is to inherit from CDialog then add data members and event handlers to the derived class. In this case the project wizard has already done this for you in CMyDlg. USe the MFC class wizard to add the data members and event handlers.

Comment: How do I use the MFC class wizard to add data members and event handlers for CMyDlg that I can access and change in another class?